# Merging [tag: battery] and [tag:battery-operated]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think that Why these two tags have different meaning, they can be merged to include all the questions relating to batteries, which means also battery powered circuits.

What do you think?

Comment: There is a distinction between battery technology and circuits intended to operate on batteries, but I don't know if these particular are intended for that distinction or make it clear if they do.

Comment: @OlinLathrop indeed I'm not saying that it's the same thing, just that a global tag makes sense to me

Comment: What about charging batteries?

Comment: @endolith as I said, to me there could be an unique tag regarding batteries.

Answer (score 3):

I think that, rather than merging these tags into a single, more ambiguous [battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) tag, we should better define the tags.

We have:

- [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries)
- [battery-operated](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-operated)
- [battery-charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging)
- [lead-acid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead-acid)
- [lithium-ion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-ion)
- [cell-battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-battery)

With these more detailed tags, it's hard to find a question on which [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) would be *more* useful.  Olin [makes the point](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/merging-tag-battery-and-tagbattery-operated#comment2588_1090) that it could be used for distinguishing battery technology and circuits which operate on batteries, but that should be obvious from the tag name and it's not if the tag name is [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries).

Accordingly, I've created the [battery-chemistry](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-chemistry) tag.  I think this is more meaningful than the alternative [battery-technology](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-technology) tag while still being broad enough. (What battery technology questions might we have that wouldn't be fundamentally about the chemistry? If I'm wrong, let me know and I can fix it with a few keystrokes).

There are 223 questions tagged [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries), do 10-20 at a time and this ambiguity will be cleared up quickly.  Be careful not to overwhelm the front page with your edits, we don't want the first 5 pages to be all battery questions and the site to become [batteries.stackexchange.com](http://batteries.stackexchange.com) until new questions get asked.

Note, too, that if you have 500 rep that you can unilaterally [retag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) a question using the 'retag' button.  If you have over 2000 rep (edit privileges), this becomes an 'edit tags' text which appears next to the tags on hover.  If you don't have the privileges to retag or edit unilaterally, feel free to suggest these as edits, but please make sure that there are no glaring needs for edits in the question - If you suggest an edit of the tags and the body of the question desperately needs editing too, your edit may be rejected.

Comment: the batteries.SE link is broken!

Answer (score -1):

No.  Don't merge.
Useful as separate entities.
 By all means better define them.

Comment: How should we define them?